# I need to transfer post from my wp site to another wp site with the help of a plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to migrate specific content of one wp website to another wp site. With the help of a plugin. i used importeer wordpress plugin but the media didnt came with the posts. I tried different plugins like all-in-one migration but that replaced the hole database and theme. I dont have access to ftp so thats also not a option.

Comment: 1 - What have you tried? 2 - How is this related to code? This should either be on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com or somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Follow below steps
On site 1 (say old site)

1. Login to WordPress Dashboard and Go to tools-> Export
2. On next screen click Media [2A]
3. Press export and download export file

On site 2 (Say new site)

1. Login to WordPress Dashboard and Go to tools-> Import {you will need to install wordpress importer first}
2. Browse the file you have downloaded in above steps.
3. Click import and following on screen steps.

All your media has been imported to new site.

Now follow above steps again. But this time select Posts while exporting content in above steps [2A]

Comment: I did this exactly but the posts came without a tumbnail and all the other media

Comment: You will need to import media first. Then you will import post in an another procedure